# Allow only a particular use to create, update and delete the record in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a webapp, in which user can authenticate and write quotes. Can anyone help me by advising appropriate rule combination to write in firestore so that the a particular user who has written the quote can only delete/update that and not anyone. Here is the hierarchy of file structure.
[image]

,and here is what i am using right now, it's working fine for `allquotes` collection but not for `userQuotes`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /allquotes/{data} {
      allow read;
      allow create, update, delete : if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /{userId}/{document=**}{
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow create, update, delete : if userId == request.auth.uid 
    }
  }
}
```

..And here is the flutter code, I am using to update the entries.

```
CollectionReference collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userQuotes');

var globalDisplay = {
      "uid": uid,
      "quote": quote,
      "author": name,
      "likes": 0,
    };


await collectionReference.doc(uid).update({
      "data": FieldValue.arrayUnion([globalDisplay])
```

By using the current rules, I am getting this error message when i try to either update/create/delete.

[image]

Thank you in advance, for even reading this problem.

Comment: Is the document name under userQuotes the same id as the user auth that it corresponds to.

Comment: yes, @Gabe . User can only update his own quotes. So Uid will be the same.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: So sorry @DougStevenson, I was not aware of that. Can you please let me know which part was creating confusion.

Comment: It's the picture full of error text.  You can simply copy that text into the question.